# How to Select All Div's which have a children image with some specfic src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have,

```
<div>
  <img src='aaBB_a.png' />
</div>

<div>
  <img src='aaa_a.png' />
</div>

<div>
  <img src='aaBB_a.png' />
</div>
```

I need to select all div's (not images) which contain a img child which src contain BB_. In above example, I need to select first and third(not second). I have tried this,

```
'div img[src*="BB_"]',
```

But it is selecting images not div.

**Update**: I need to pass this to jquery delegate,

$('#container').delegate('div img[src*="BB_"]','mouseover',function(){
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to filter the initial result to those that *has* these descendants

```
var divsBB = $('div').has('img[src*="BB_"]');
```

For the [selector version  `:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$('#container').delegate('div:has(>img[src*="BB_"])','mouseover',function(){...})
```

Comment: Is it not possible with one selector, because I need to pass this to jquery delegate.

Comment: @user960567 how does this get passed? can you show in your post? you can chain delegate to it by the way.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But also selecting the other parents. For example, parent of div img. I need to select only immediate div.

Comment: This works for me, div:has(>img[src*="BB_"]). Please update your answer. Very much Thanks.

Comment: I tried that in the method version, but didn't work. I guess it works in the selector version :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div img[src*="BB_"]').parent("div");
```

I think that this will work

Comment: Is it not possible with one selector, because I need to pass this to jquery delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the parent of each  tag by using `$('some_kind_img').parent()`